# Not able to find tooltip in the document

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library, react-dom

So I am using tooltip from Salt Design System in my code
https://www.saltdesignsystem.com/salt/components/tooltip/examples

I am trying to write a test using React Testing Library.
But I could not find the tooltip in the document when I fire the mouseover event on button.
Below is my component code and unit test.
What could I be doing wrong ?

**App.tsx**

```js
import { Button, Tooltip } from "@salt-ds/core";

function App() {
  return (
    <Tooltip content="hakuna matata">
      <Button>Click me</Button>
    </Tooltip>
  );
}
export default App;
```

**App.spec.tsx**

```js
import {
  act,
  fireEvent,
  render,
  screen,
  waitFor,
} from "@testing-library/react";
import App from "./App";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";

describe("App", () => {
  it("should open tooltip", async () => {
    render(<App />);
    const btn = screen.getByText("Click me");
    expect(btn).toBeInTheDocument();
    fireEvent.mouseOver(btn);
    expect(await screen.findByText("hakuna matata")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

**UPDATE**

One thing I noticed in inspect element is that the tooltip is kind of rendered like a portal outside the root element

[image]

Comment: It's difficult to say, we may need more code, and CSS, but I've often had this issue when the parent element (whatever that may be) doesn't explicitly have `position: relative` on it.

Comment: ^ There's no way to know what's happening here without seeing the contents of your `<Tooltip>` component or even knowing if `mouseOver` is triggering the logic inside `<Tooltip>` for it to show itself.

Comment: One thing I noticed in inspect element is that the tooltip is kind of rendered like a portal outside the `root` element

Comment: Is there as specific reason you're using `fireEvent`?  Perhaps `user-event` hover would do it?  This function fires of several events that simulate a hover above and beyond `mouseOver`.

https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/v13#hoverelement-options